# how to change path when including file with gulp-inject

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

I'm injecting files like this right now:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');

gulp.task('inject_rev', function () {
    var target = gulp.src('webapp/dist/somefolder/index.html');
    var sources = gulp.src(['webapp/dist/somefolder/*.js',], {read: false});

    return target.pipe(inject(sources))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('webapp/dist/somefolder/'));
});
```

But in html file it includes not the path I need, how can I change this path? So for example instead of this:

```
<script src="/webapp/dist/somefolder/script-1253fe56bd.js"></script>
```

I could have this:

```
<script src="/my/own/directory/script-1253fe56bd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that you are referring that the dist folder is ok, that will be the public folder, but you need to change only the script-src attribute, to match the respective cdn/static source locations.
try this :

```
       .pipe( $.inject(
        gulp.src( ['src/main/webapp/static/dist/**/*.js'], { read : false } ), {
            addRootSlash : false,
            //ignorePath : 'src/main/webapp',
            transform : function ( filePath, file, i, length ) {
                var newPath = filePath.replace( 'src/main/webapp/', '' );
                console.log('inject script = '+ newPath);
                return '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/' + newPath  + '"></script>';
            }
        } ))
    .pipe( $.inject(
        gulp.src( ['src/main/webapp/static/dist/**/*.css'], { read : false } ), {
            addRootSlash : false,
            //ignorePath : 'src/main/webapp',
            transform : function ( filePath, file, i, length ) {
                var newPath = filePath.replace( 'src/main/webapp/', '' );
                console.log('inject style = '+ newPath);
                return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/' + newPath + '"/>';
            }
        } ))
```

change the gulp.src, replace() to match your environment

#### edit  full gulp.js file used in a java application.

In my opinion you should remove the parts that you don't need, and start from scratch, adding one feature after another.

here is my gulpfile

```
var gulp = require( 'gulp' );
var concat = require( 'gulp-concat' );
// var concatCss = require( 'gulp-concat-css' );
var uglifyCss = require( 'gulp-uglifycss' );
var uglify = require( 'gulp-uglify' );
var minify = require( 'gulp-minify' );
var usemin = require( 'gulp-usemin' );
var imagemin = require( 'gulp-imagemin' );
// var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
var sourcemaps = require( 'gulp-sourcemaps' );
var del = require( 'del' );
var dir = require( 'node-dir' );
var wiredep = require( 'wiredep' ).stream;
var debug = require( 'gulp-debug' );
var runSequence = require( 'run-sequence' );
var bower = require( 'gulp-bower' );
var $ = require( 'gulp-load-plugins' )();
var livereload = require( 'gulp-livereload' );
var injectReload = require( 'gulp-inject-reload' );
var noop = require( 'gulp-util' ).noop;
var plumber = require( 'gulp-plumber' );
var expect = require( 'gulp-expect-file' );
var liveReloadEnabled = false;
var mainBowerFiles = require( 'main-bower-files' );
var bower = require( 'gulp-bower' );
var gutil = require( 'gulp-util' );
var babel = require( 'gulp-babel' );

var browserify = require( 'gulp-browserify' );
var webserver = require( 'gulp-webserver' );

// var minimist = require('minimist');
global.Promise = require( 'bluebird' );
var Q = require( 'q' );

var DEBUG = false;
var SOURCE_MAPS = false;
var PROD = false;

var liveReloadPort = 21232;

var bower_components = 'bower_components';

var paths = {
    scripts : ['src/main/javascript/**/*.js*'],// ,'!src/main/webapp/static/dist/**/*'
    raw_scripts : ['src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/raw_scripts/**/*.jsp*'],
    css : ['src/main/css/**/*.css'],
    // bower_dir : 'src/main/webapp/' + bower_components,
    bower_dir : bower_components,
// images: 'client/img/**/*'
};

gulp.task( 'main-files', function () {
    return gulp.src( mainBowerFiles(), {
        base : 'bower_components'
    } ).pipe( gulp.dest( 'src/main/webapp/bower_components' ) );
} );

gulp.task( 'scripts-dev', function () {
    return gulp.src( paths.scripts )//
        .pipe( babel( {
            plugins : ['transform-react-jsx', 'transform-runtime'],
            presets : ['es2015']
        } ) )
        .pipe( DEBUG ? debug() : noop() )//
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'src/main/webapp/static/dist/js/' ) )//
} );

gulp.task( 'scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src( paths.scripts )//
        .pipe( babel( {
            plugins : ['transform-react-jsx'],
            presets : ['es2015']
        } ) )
        .pipe( DEBUG ? debug() : noop() )//
        .pipe( SOURCE_MAPS || (!PROD) ? sourcemaps.init() : noop() )//
        .pipe( uglify( {
            mangle : false
        } ).on( 'error', gutil.log ) )//
        .on( 'error', handleError )//
        .pipe( concat( 'bundle.js' ) )//
        .pipe( SOURCE_MAPS || (!PROD) ? sourcemaps.write( './' ) : noop() )//
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'src/main/webapp/static/dist/' ) )//
        .pipe( liveReloadEnabled ? livereload() : noop() );
} );

gulp.task( 'styles-dev', function () {
    return gulp.src( paths.css )//
        .pipe( DEBUG ? debug() : noop() )//
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'src/main/webapp/static/dist/css/' ) )//
} );

gulp.task( 'styles', function () {
    return gulp.src( paths.css )//
        .pipe( DEBUG ? debug() : noop() )//
        .pipe( SOURCE_MAPS || (!PROD) ? sourcemaps.init() : noop() )//
        .pipe( uglifyCss() ).pipe( concat( 'bundle.css' ) )//
        .pipe( SOURCE_MAPS || (!PROD) ? sourcemaps.write( './' ) : noop() )//
        .on( 'error', handleError )//
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'src/main/webapp/static/dist/' ) )//
        .pipe( liveReloadEnabled ? livereload() : noop() );//
} );

var runUseminForFile = function ( file, base, onEnd ) {
    return gulp.src( file, { base : base } )
        .pipe( DEBUG ? debug() : noop() )
        .pipe( usemin( {
            path : base,
            //cssnano() seems it does not work
            css : [SOURCE_MAPS ? sourcemaps.init( { loadMaps : true } ) : noop(), uglifyCss( { uglyComments : true } ), 'concat', SOURCE_MAPS ? sourcemaps.write( './' ) : noop()],
            // uglify() //uglify( { mangle : false } )// uglify( { mangle : false } ).on('error', gutil.log)//minify({ignoreFiles: [ 'min.js']}),
            js : [SOURCE_MAPS ? sourcemaps.init( { loadMaps : true } ) : noop(), uglify( { mangle : false } ).on( 'error', gutil.log ), 'concat', SOURCE_MAPS ? sourcemaps.write( './' ) : noop()]
        } ) )//
        .pipe( gulp.dest( function () {
            var remainingFolder = file.substring( file.indexOf( base ) + base.length, file.lastIndexOf( '/' ) + 1 );
            if ( DEBUG === true )
                console.log( file, remainingFolder, base );
            return './tmp/vendor/' + remainingFolder + '/';
        } ) )
        .on( 'end', onEnd );
};

gulp.task( 'usemin', ['wiredep'], function ( cb ) {
    // return
    dir.files( './tmp/', function ( err, files ) {
        var deferredList = [];
        if ( err )
            throw err;
        for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
            var deferred = Q.defer();
            var file = files[i];
            if ( file.indexOf( '.jsp' ) === -1 )
                continue;
            if ( DEBUG === true )
                console.log( 'usemin for : ' + './' + file );
            runUseminForFile( './' + file, './tmp/', deferred.resolve );

            deferredList.push( deferred.promise );
        }
        Q.all( deferredList ).then( function () {
            cb();
        } );
    } );

} );

gulp.task( 'debug', function ( cb ) {
    DEBUG = true;
    cb();
} );
gulp.task( 'sourcemaps', function ( cb ) {
    SOURCE_MAPS = true;
    cb();
} );

gulp.task( 'clean', function () {

    return del.sync( ['tmp/', 'src/main/webapp/bower_components', 'src/main/webapp/static/dist',
        'src/main/webapp/static/vendor'], function ( err, paths ) {
        if ( DEBUG === true )
            console.log( 'Deleted files/folders:\n', paths.join( '\n' ) );
    } );

} );

gulp.task( 'copy-bower-fonts', function () {
    return gulp.src( paths.bower_dir + '/**/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}', {
        base : paths.bower_dir
    } ).pipe( DEBUG ? debug() : noop() )//
        .pipe( gulp.dest( './src/main/webapp/static/vendor/font/' ) );
} );

gulp.task( 'copy-bower-images', function () {
    return gulp.src( paths.bower_dir + '/**/*.{png,jpg,svg}', {
        base : paths.bower_dir
    } ).pipe( DEBUG ? debug() : noop() )//
        .pipe( gulp.dest( './src/main/webapp/static/images/' ) );
} );

gulp.task( 'min-and-replace', ['usemin'], function ( cb ) {
    // the base option sets the relative root for the set of files,
    // preserving the folder structure
    gulp.src( ['tmp/vendor/**/*.jsp*'], {
        base : './tmp/vendor/'
    } )//
        .pipe( DEBUG ? debug() : noop() )//
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/scripts/' ) ).on( 'end', function () {

        gulp.src( ['tmp/vendor/**/*.js', 'tmp/vendor/**/*.css'], {
            base : './tmp/vendor/${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/'
        } ).pipe( DEBUG ? debug() : noop() )//
            .pipe( gulp.dest( 'src/main/webapp/static/' ) ).on( 'end', function () {

            del.sync( ['tmp/'], function ( err, paths ) {
                if ( DEBUG === true )
                    console.log( 'Deleted files/folders:\n', paths.join( '\n' ) );
            } );

            cb();

        } );

    } );

} );


gulp.task( 'wiredep', ['sync-install-scripts-styles'], function () {
    return gulp.src( paths.raw_scripts )//
        .pipe( DEBUG ? debug() : noop() )//
        .pipe( wiredep( {
            directory : paths.bower_dir,//
            dependencies : true, // default: true
            devDependencies : true, // default: false
            // ignorePath : '../../',
            fileTypes : {
                jsp : {
                    replace : {
                        js : function ( filePath ) {
                            var newPath = filePath.substring( filePath.indexOf( bower_components ) + bower_components.length );
                            if ( DEBUG === true )
                                console.log( 'bower script  = ' + newPath );

                            return '<script src="../' + paths.bower_dir + newPath + '"></script>';
                        },
                        css : function ( filePath ) {
                            var newPath = filePath.substring( filePath.indexOf( bower_components ) + bower_components.length );
                            if ( DEBUG === true )
                                console.log( 'bower style = ' + newPath );
                            return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../' + paths.bower_dir + newPath + '"/>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } ) )//
        .pipe( $.inject( gulp.src( ['src/main/webapp/static/dist/**/*.js'], {
            read : false
        } ), {
            addRootSlash : false,
            // ignorePath : 'src/main/webapp',
            transform : function ( filePath, file, i, length ) {
                var newPath = filePath.replace( 'src/main/webapp/', '' );
                if ( DEBUG === true )
                    console.log( 'inject script = ' + newPath );
                return '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/' + newPath + '"></script>';
            }
        } ) )//
        .pipe( $.inject( gulp.src( ['src/main/webapp/static/dist/**/*.css'], {
            read : false
        } ), {
            addRootSlash : false,
            // ignorePath : 'src/main/webapp',
            transform : function ( filePath, file, i, length ) {
                var newPath = filePath.replace( 'src/main/webapp/', '' );
                if ( DEBUG === true )
                    console.log( 'inject style = ' + newPath );
                return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/' + newPath + '"/>';
            }
        } ) )//
        .pipe( gulp.dest( './tmp/' ) );
} );

gulp.task( 'sync-install-scripts-styles', function ( cb ) {
    runSequence( 'install', ['scripts', 'styles'], cb );
} );

gulp.task( 'wiredep-live', function ( cb ) {
    return gulp.src( paths.raw_scripts )//
        .pipe( DEBUG ? debug() : noop() )//
        .pipe( wiredep( {
            directory : paths.bower_dir,//
            dependencies : true, // default: true
            devDependencies : true, // default: false
            // ignorePath : '../../../../',
            fileTypes : {
                jsp : {
                    replace : {
                        js : function ( filePath ) {
                            var newPath = filePath.substring( filePath.indexOf( bower_components ) );
                            if ( DEBUG === true )
                                console.log( 'bower script = ' + newPath );
                            return '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/' + newPath + '"></script>';
                        },
                        css : function ( filePath ) {
                            var newPath = filePath.substring( filePath.indexOf( bower_components ) );
                            if ( DEBUG === true )
                                console.log( 'bower style = ' + newPath );
                            return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/' + newPath + '"/>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } ) )//
        .pipe( $.inject( gulp.src( ['src/main/webapp/static/dist/**/*.js'], {
            read : false
        } ), {
            addRootSlash : false,
            // ignorePath : 'src/main/webapp',
            transform : function ( filePath, file, i, length ) {
                var newPath = filePath.replace( 'src/main/webapp/', '' );
                if ( DEBUG === true )
                    console.log( 'inject script = ' + newPath );
                return '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/' + newPath + '"></script>';
            }
        } ) )//
        .pipe( $.inject( gulp.src( ['src/main/webapp/static/dist/**/*.css'], {
            read : false
        } ), {
            addRootSlash : false,
            // ignorePath : 'src/main/webapp',
            transform : function ( filePath, file, i, length ) {
                var newPath = filePath.replace( 'src/main/webapp/', '' );
                if ( DEBUG === true )
                    console.log( 'inject style = ' + newPath );
                return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/' + newPath + '"/>';
            }
        } ) )//
        .pipe( liveReloadEnabled ? injectReload( {
            port : liveReloadPort,
            host : 'http://localhost'
        } ) : noop() ).pipe( gulp.dest( './src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/scripts/' ) );
} );

gulp.task( 'wiredep-full-live', function ( cb ) {
    runSequence( 'sync-install-scripts-styles', 'wiredep-live', cb );
} );

// Copy all static images
// gulp.task('images', ['clean'], function() {
// return gulp.src(paths.images)
// // Pass in options to the task
// .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5}))
// .pipe(gulp.dest('build/img'));
// });

// Rerun the task when a file changes
gulp.task( 'watch', function () {
    liveReloadEnabled = true;
    livereload.listen( liveReloadPort );
    runSequence( 'wiredep-full-live' );
    gulp.watch( paths.scripts, ['scripts'] );
    gulp.watch( paths.css, ['styles'] );
    gulp.watch( paths.raw_scripts, ['wiredep-live'] );
    gulp.watch( ['bower.json'], ['wiredep-full-live'] );

} );

function handleError( error ) {

    // If you want details of the error in the console
    console.log( error.toString() );

    if ( liveReloadEnabled === true )
        this.emit( 'end' );
    else
        fail( error );
}

gulp.task( 'live-reload', function () {
    return gulp.src( './src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/scripts/**/*.jsp*' ).pipe( injectReload( {
        host : 'http://localhost'
    } ) ).pipe( gulp.dest( './src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/scripts/' ) );
} );

gulp.task( 'del-components', function () {
    del.sync( 'target/**/bower_components', function ( err, paths ) {
        if ( DEBUG === true )
            console.log( 'Deleted files/folders:\n', paths.join( '\n' ) );
    } );
} );

gulp.task( 'dev', ['clean', 'sourcemaps', 'wiredep-full-live'] );

gulp.task( 'stage', function ( cb ) {
    runSequence( 'clean', 'wiredep-full-live', cb );
} );

gulp.task( 'prod', function ( cb ) {
    PROD = true;
    runSequence( 'clean', 'min-and-replace', cb );// , 'del-components'
} );

gulp.task( 'install', function ( cb ) {
    runSequence( 'bower-install', 'main-files', cb );
} );

gulp.task( 'js', function () {
    return gulp.src( "src/main/javascript/app.js" )
        .pipe( browserify( {
            transform : 'reactify',
            debug : true
        } ) )
        .on( 'error', function ( err ) {
            console.error( 'Error!', err.message );
        } )
        .pipe( concat( 'bundle.js' ) )//
        .pipe( gulp.dest( "src/main/webapp/static/dist/" ) );
} );
gulp.task( 'ss', function ( cb ) {
    runSequence( 'clean', 'js', cb );
} );
// gulp.task('webserver', function() {
//  gulp.src( app + '/')
//      .pipe(webserver({
//          livereload: true,
//          open: true
//      }));
// });

gulp.task( 'default', ['watch', 'html', 'js', 'css', 'webserver'] );

//gulp.task( 'bower-install', function( cb ) {
//  bower.commands.install( [], {
//      save : true
//  }, {} ).on( 'end', function( installed ) {
//      cb( ); // notify gulp that this task is finished
//  } );
//} );
gulp.task( 'bower-install', function ( cb ) {
    return bower();
} );

// The default task (called when you run `gulp` from cli)
gulp.task( 'default', ['clean', 'dev'] ); // 'images' // 'watch'
```

Comment: Hi Radu Im new to gulp, can you provide a complete example using your solution?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `ignorePath` attribute

```
 gulp.src(paths.html)
       .pipe(inject(gulp.src('_YOUR_PATH_', {read: false}), {ignorePath: '/webapp', addRootSlash: false}))
```